# asp.net list view paging show broken data when search

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datapager

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetData();

            }
        }

public void GetData()
        { 
        string SQL=string.Empty;
            SqlDataAdapter commandToBeLog=null;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlcon"].ConnectionString);

                SQL = " SELECT * FROM tbl_Video";
                if (txtSearchVideo.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    SQL += " WHERE VideoName LIKE  @VideoName ";
                    ListView1.DataSource = null;
                }
                SQL += " ORDER BY VideoID DESC";

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(
                           SQL, con);

                if (txtSearchVideo.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                {
                    myCommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@VideoName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = "%" + txtSearchVideo.Text + "%";
                }

                myCommand.Fill(ds);

                ListView1.DataSource = ds;
                ListView1.DataBind();
           }

protected void ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows,             false);
            this.GetData();


        }

        protected void btnSerch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (txtSearchVideo.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
            {
                GetData();
                GetData();
            }
            else
            {

                GetData();
            }

        }
```

Hi, how do i make the list view paging is no depedent to the textbox search. I got a problem with listview search pager, whenever I click search button with textbox value equal to A, the  btnSerch_Click event fire. It show out 3 pages data with results and then I navigate to page 3. But when I type in the textbox with value B(it suppose show one page data), and I didnt click search button, but i go to click page 2. The weird thing happen, it show not relevant data or broken data.

How do i solve this problem, i don't want the page navigate bar depedent to the textbox. What I mean is I click page 2, the GetData() fucntion not fire, but just the page trigger only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to remove this line

```
ListView1.DataSource = null;
```

from the `GetData` method. Because if you `null` the ListView, the properties you set in `ListView1_PagePropertiesChanging` will be lost.

And you can reduce the Button click method to just one line.

```
protected void btnSerch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}
```

Comment: I had try your solution, but seem like the pager still not work normally

Comment: If i do not trigger GetData() two times, the result would not come out, how do I solved it?

Comment: That seems unlikely, but what happens if you fix the original error by removing `ListView1.DataSource = null;`

Comment: And did you place the DataPager inside the ListView?

Comment: I didnt place the datapager inside the listview, will it cause the problem if I didnt place the data pager inside the list view?